# Sails.js - How to get the current request outside of a controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm wondering how to access to req/res outside the scope of a controller in sails.js.

I'm writing a helper (kinda a service) that would need to access to `req` without having to send it as parameter, so somehow I need it as global value.

Comment: Why exactly can't you send `req` as a parameter?

Comment: Because I'm in a view, not in a controller. i don't think I can access to req from a view.

Comment: Hmm...have you tried?  (Hint: you can).

Comment: Good hint! Do you know if it is also available from the global `sails` object?

Comment: No. `sails` is, as you said, a global object representing the entire Sails application.  Anywhere where it would be appropriate to use `req` in your code, you can pass it in as an argument.  If you find you don't have access to it, chances are you're trying to do something you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS [Domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) can do what you're looking for. You could create a middleware/policy that creates a new `domain` for each request, and sets the req object as a property on the `domain`. You could then just access the property from the `domain` object.

That said, this seems like a code smell. You might want to look at converting your service into a `Class` and just instantiate it with the `req`. Then you could just pass around the `service` in your code.

Comment: That's not what I want to do but that's a possibility, thanks.

Comment: Yikes, don't do this.  This is not what domains are for!

Comment: @sgress454 I agree that domains are definitely not the way to go in this case (and it looks like they are being deprecated/respecc'd) but I can see how something like global transactional context might be useful: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/enabling-transactions-in-node-js-using-domains/#Domains and https://www.npmjs.org/package/domain-context